# Power bi how to initialize service client credentials in .net sdk

Tags: c#, powerbi, .net-6.0

I'm using Microsoft.PowerBI.Api nuget package and follow through this sample under the [repo](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-CSharp).

Client expects credentials and I cannot figure out how to initialize it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need initialize new ServiceClientCredentials and pass in PowerBIClient constructor at line 26 (using statement)

What type of authentication do you want to use?
Basic (username and password)
token ?
Windows authentication ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: ServiceClientCredentials is an abstract class, so cannot initialize a new one. There has to be a factory method to do this.

Comment: I agree that this class is abstract, however, depending on the type of authentication you want to apply, you must use the correct class which inherits from this abstract class.
So I repeat my question: "What type of authentication do you want?"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I could not found the concrete classes anywhere in the documentations. Your answer helped me to find it out.